# How to store json data to azure table storage which should add as each row from a single json string?

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I have a message structure in the following format

```
{"deviceId":"D1","t":"2017-07-07T12:31:21Z","i1":"112.50","i2":"150.75","i3":"406.25","type":"Instant"}
```

What I am trying to do is save this data into azure table storage in the following format

[image]

I can add this in a single row with i1,i2,i3 as column. But I need this in the specified structure. 
The following query is used in stream analytics to store data to table storage. This is working. But I need additional table to store data as specified above.

```
SELECT
deviceId,
TRY_CAST(t AS datetime) as Row,
i1,
i2,
i3,
type
INTO
[iothubstorage] 
FROM
[iotinput] timestamp by t
```

This is working. But I need additional table to store data as specified above. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use UNION to combine the 3 rows, sample code below is for your reference. I tested it and it worked fine on my side.

```
With firstQueryResult AS (SELECT
CONCAT(TRY_CAST(deviceId as nvarchar(max)) , ' - i1') as PartitionKey,
t as RowKey,
TRY_CAST(t AS datetime) as TimeReceived,
CONCAT(TRY_CAST(deviceId as nvarchar(max)) , ' - i1') as deviceId,
'i1' as Input,
i1 as Value FROM [iotinput] 
UNION 
SELECT
CONCAT(TRY_CAST(deviceId as nvarchar(max)) , ' - i2') as PartitionKey,
t as RowKey,
TRY_CAST(t AS datetime) as TimeReceived,
CONCAT(TRY_CAST(deviceId as nvarchar(max)) , ' - i2') as deviceId,
'i2' as Input,
i2 as Value FROM [iotinput]
UNION 
SELECT
CONCAT(TRY_CAST(deviceId as nvarchar(max)) , ' - i3') as PartitionKey,
t as RowKey,
TRY_CAST(t AS datetime) as TimeReceived,
CONCAT(TRY_CAST(deviceId as nvarchar(max)) , ' - i3') as deviceId,
'i3' as Input,
i3 as Value FROM [iotinput])

SELECT * INTO
[iothubstorage] FROM firstQueryResult
```

Comment: I tried. But showing error when using where condition

Comment: Where did you use 'where' condition?